# How can I achieve Patent Protection?

Tags: achievements, team-fortress-2, tf2-engineer

The Engineer achievement Patent Protection is eluding me.

The achievement's description is:

> Destroy an enemy Engineer's sentry gun
>   with a sentry under control of your
>   Wrangler.

I've destroyed mini-sentries and regular sentries currently being built with a wrangled Mini-Sentry, but still haven't gotten this achievement.

Are there any restrictions as to what type of sentry you're using, what type of sentry they have, and the enemy sentry's build status?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You will not get the achievement if the enemy sentry is in the construction process and it must be a regular sentry. Your sentry on the other hand can be any kind.

> The Wrangler allows your Sentry Gun to
>   shoot at an enemy Sentry Gun from
>   outside of its range, unless the enemy
>   Engineer is using the Wrangler as
>   well. On the offense, try to haul your
>   Sentry Gun into a position where you
>   can easily attack the enemy
>   Engineer's, the element of surprise is
>   often enough to force other players to
>   abandon their building nests. Unless
>   your Sentry Gun is level 3, try to
>   make sure the enemy Engineer is not
>   nearby, or kill him or her before
>   attempting to destroy the Sentry Gun,
>   as the Engineer will be able to repair
>   any damage done to it otherwise. Be on
>   the lookout for other Engineers trying
>   to deploy their Sentry Guns around
>   corners and use the rockets of a level
>   3 to destroy them. Destroying a Combat
>   Mini-Sentry does not count towards
>   this achievement.

http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Obtaining_Engineer_achievements

Comment: Suggestion: Build a mini-sentry out of range of a level 3 sentry.  Wrangle it.  Laugh as your puny sentry decimates its bigger brother.